# Lua cjson testing for null

Tags: lua

I am using `cjson` to decode the following JSON. I want to test for the case that the items parameter is null. I am having difficulty finding a conditional to match this case. It's weird because it seems like it is not a string, not nil, but stil has a truthy value.

```
{
  "kind": "ServiceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/services",
    "resourceVersion": "47316"
  },
  "items": null
}
```

Here are the conditionals that I have tried:

`if jsonServices.items == "null" then`

`if jsonServices.items == null then`

`if not jsonServices.items then`

`if jsonServices.items == nil`

Comment: What does `print(jsonServices.items)` show?

Answer (score 9):

found [this](https://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html#_decode) in the Lua docs

`if jsonServices.items == cjson.null then`

works great!

Comment: It is sad that cjson doesn't convert null into Lua nil. Anyway, this is how cjson handle null.